# Under what circumstances is it permissable to stay overnight in the office?

Tags: professionalism, work-life-balance

Due to an unexpected weather event last night my evening commute time was quadrupled, and I had to be back at work only 4 hours after I was able to pull in to my own driveway.  It didn't occur to me until today that since I'm usually first one in to work and the last to leave that no one would have been able to tell that I never went home.  When is it okay to turn a laptop case in to a pillow and sleep overnight in the office?

Comment: Do you have cleaning services that come in? That would be my only hesitation to not do this. Also company culture would probably define if this is acceptable. I work at a small company that wouldn't think anything of it. (Though because of my position they'd wonder why I wasn't working from home. Your circumstances might be different).

Comment: @Sirisian Cleaning service comes in at 7pm like clockwork, but as there are only 4 of us they aren't in here for long.  I'm new here, but from what I've gathered there has to be accumulated snow before we can boot up our VPN's and try to convince or SO's that although we are home the headphones mean that I am working.

Comment: This would be _entirely_ company policy specific.  However, if there was the likelihood of physical danger by leaving, then I suggest most organisations would be compassionate about a very rare exception.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello Yes, I work west of the beltway and live on the opposite side.  Waze was practically begging me to get off the inner loop before 95.

Comment: Only your manager can answer this question.

Comment: Another reason I can think of not to stay overnight is if the office is locked up overnight, and there are motion sensors connected to the burglar alarm.  You don't want to set the alarm off and have the out-of-hours security guards turning up to search the place.

Comment: I once worked all night to repair a customer's database: arrived at 8 am and left at 5 am the next morning. I'd say this depends on the company and on your position. If you're a new hire or this is a big, regimented company they might be worried you're going to steal something or vandalize the place. If you're a reasonably trusted employee, especially if you have a key to the building, maybe nobody much cares.

Comment: If there's no shower at work, this is quite unprofessional. Laptop case doesn't make a nice pillow, either. Some companies have real cots for napping.

Comment: Permissions aside, if you make a habit of doing this, it may not be good. The problem with asking your manager about this is that he may deduce from this that you're working too much or perhaps working ineffectively.

Answer (score 2):

Circumstances in which I have overnighted. This is just my personal view, I'd rather have four hours at home than sleeping on my laptop case.

If I had urgent work that HAD to be completed, this has happened a few times in disaster recovery situations.

Cyclone made it unsafe to leave, this happened once.

Too drunk to care, a couple of office parties in my youth left human wreckage strewn around the place until morning.

In your particular scenario, it would be appropriate to ask your boss first and not make a habit of it.